# 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy Laravel8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, html2canvas

I am getting this error when I assess an image using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Access to image at 'http://testdomain.com/storage/images/products/user_front.png' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my cors config.

```
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

Here the header, when I access the image.
[image]

Any one can help me?

Comment: i am not sure you are exactly looking for this, try to config with options of html2canvas

Whether to attempt to load images from a server using CORS
in html2canvas 

"useCORS false"

Comment: When I use CORS false, The image is getting getting printed. Boz I am loading the image from another domain

Comment: is it working for you

Comment: No. It's not working.

Answer (score -1):

Html to canvas uses  element in DOM that's why it's requiring a cors from your public folder but laravel does not support that, it only supports cors with api. You need to change your config file.

If you are using nginx use this:

```
location /storage/ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}
```

Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp|pdf)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Take note that you need to change the Access-Control-Allow-Origin when deploying to prod to only accept the valid server origin.

Comment: That header must be set on the **requested** resource, otherwise this defeats the whole purpose of CORS.

Comment: @Terry Thats why I said he needs to change it when deploying in prod but for development it shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: @RyanGarde , Its not working. I am using apache server.